# jenkins pipeline DOCKER_HOST

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a **docker-container inside my pipeline**.
My problem is, there is **no docker.sock** available inside the Jenkins-container. And actual no chance to get it.

But I found some jobs using docker with this Option:

> "Inject environment variables to the build process" -> "Properties
>   Content"

And following configured:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<ip>:<port>
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/var/jenkins_home/certs
```

In my understanding, this is equivalent to the docker.sock and useable as plugin, isnt it?

But how can i use it inside a (multi-)pipeline project?
I've tried using this Block inside my Note:

```
environment {
    DOCKER_HOST         = 'tcp://<ip>:<port>'
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH    = '/var/jenkins_home/certs'
}
```

But got same issue: **"docker: not found"**
I might have a logical fallacy. Hope someone could help.

Otherwise is it possible to create a jenkins-slave including a docker.sock?

Comment: Probably cloudBees plugin will help you in this case. https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#docker-workflow

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: No, sorry. we recreated the jenkins container

Answer (score 0):

> But got same issue: **"docker: not found"**

This indicates that your Jenkins slave, the one running the pipeline script, does not have the `docker` command line tools. This depends on your distribution, but in my case I fixed it by changing my build-slave/pipeline-runner creation steps to include:

```
yum install -y docker-client
```

Note that you'll still need that for the Cloudbees docker plugin (the thing which provides stuff like `docker.build()` and `docker.image()`) because it translates those nice pipeline directives down into shell commands.